# i can't see difference between put and patch method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, nodejs-server

I just want to like a quote or dislike if already i liked the quote. So first i find the quote and then i check if i already liked the quote, if not then i like, otherwise i dislike.

I have a router like below

```
router.put('/:quoteId', isAuth, quotesController.likeQuote);
```

And likeQuote method is like below

```
module.exports.likeQuote = (req, res, next) => {
  const quoteId = req.params.quoteId;
  const userId = req.userId;
  Quote.findById(quoteId)
    .then((quote) => {
      if (quote.likes.indexOf(userId) == -1) {
        quote.likes.push(userId);
      } else {
        quote.likes.pull(userId);
      }
      return quote.save();
    })
    .then((updatedQuote) => {
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'You liked the post!' });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      err.statusCode = 500;
      next(err);
    });
```

But my question is, i just want to know how **PUT** and **PATCH** works? I think we should send all the fields in PUT but not in PATCH methods, but in my case i don't even send any fields and both work just fine.How this happens?

Comment: Methods are not limiting what you can do. I for example ussualy only use POST for insert/update and i'm fine with that. I'm not saying you should too. I'm saying you can do whatever you want. Methods are there to clarify the intention not to enforce anything.

Comment: i thought that too, but most people say you must send all the fields inside PUT method, is it a convention to send all the fields or an obligation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual REST API methods (`PUT`, `PATCH`, ... ) do not have any limitations. the logic you choose to write is what defines this. Now you're asking about "best practices" and whenever you ask about that you will get many different answers. I'll  explain my view.

`PUT`, so the essence of `PUT` is to replace the existing object completely, that's why people are telling you to send the entire object because when you use `PUT` what's expected is a complete swap.

`PATCH`, the essence of `PATCH` is to update the existing resource. which is in your case what you're looking for, in this case you just send the required fields you need for the update.

Now is it wrong if you write `PUT` to be an update and not a complete swap? I would argue it is not. As long as you keep consistent logic throughout your app you can build your own "best practices" that will suit your needs.

Now you did tag this question as `Mongo` related so I would like to introduce to you the concept of [piplined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) (for Mongo v4.2+) where you can execute your logic in 1 single update.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yiLFdDy24Yh)

Answer (score 1):

> i just want to know how PUT and PATCH works?

An important distinction to understand is that we don't have a standard for how PUT and PATCH *work*; that's a implementation detail, and is deliberately hidden behind the "uniform interface".

What we do have is standardized *semantics*, an agreement about what PUT and PATCH mean.

(This is further complicated by people not being familiar with the standard, and therefore misinterpretations of the meaning are common.)

If the implementation of the request handler doesn't match the semantics of the request, that's OK... but if something goes expensively wrong as a result, it's the fault of the implementation.

---

PUT and PATCH are both method-tokens that indicate that we are trying to modify the resource identified by the target-uri.  In particular, we use those method-tokens when we are trying to make the server's representation of the resource match the representation on the client.

For example, imagine editing a web page.  We `GET /home.html`, change the TITLE element in our copy, and we want to save our changes to the server.  How do we do that in HTTP?

One answer is that we send a copy of home.html (with our changes) back to the server, so that the server can save it.  That's PUT.

Another answer is that we diff our copy and the server's copy, and send to the server a patch-document that describes the changes that the server should make to it's copy.  That's PATCH.

---

```
router.put('/:quoteId', isAuth, quotesController.likeQuote);
```

What this invocation is doing is configuring the framework, so that requests with the PUT method token and a target-uri that matches "/:quoteId" are delegated to the likeQuote method.

And at this level, the framework assumes that you know what you are doing - there's no attempt to verify that "likeQuote" implements PUT semantics.  To ensure that the implementation and the request semantics match, you are going to need to do some work (inspect the code, test, etc).

> in my case i don't even send any fields and both work just fine.

Right - because the framework assumes that you know what you are doing, and your current implementation doesn't try to access or interpret the body of the HTTP request.

Note: that's a big hint that the request handler not actually implementing PUT/PATCH semantics (how could the server possibly make its copy of the quote look like the client's if it doesn't look at the information the client provided)?

[It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post); assuming that your implementation is correct, you should not be using methods with remote authoring semantics, because that's not what you are doing.  This same implementation attached to a POST route would be *fine*.

As is, things are broken - you have a mismatch between the request semantics and the handler implementation.  Under controlled conditions, you are likely to get away with it.  It's entirely possible that you are only going to be invoking this code under controlled conditions.

Comment: One final thought: if the router is sending PATCH requests to the configured PUT handler, that seems really weird, I would look around carefully to make sure that there wasn't a `router.patch` or `router.all` method that you have overlooked.